# Covariance Matrix of two random variables

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables, covariance

Can two random variables $X$ and $Y$ have the covariance matrix

$\begin{pmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ -1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}? $

The matrix is positive definite if $xy<0$. Does this imply that it could be the convariance matrix for some $X$ and $Y$?

Comment: The provided matrix is not positive definite. There also isn't an $x$ or $y$ anywhere; is there a typo?

Comment: Isn't $XAX^T=-2xy$, where $X=(x,y)$?

Comment: For $A$ to be positive definite, $XAX^\top$ must be positive for all $x,y$. If this product is negative for $xy$, then $A$ isn't positive definite.

Comment: $A$ is positive definite if and only if $\begin{bmatrix} x & y\end{bmatrix} A \begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \end{bmatrix} > 0$ for any $(x,y)$ (except $(x,y)=(0,0)$).

Comment: So this matrix can not be covariance matrix for any pair of random variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The eigenvalues of the matrix
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
0&-1\\
-1&0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
are $-1$ and $1$. The eigenvalues of a positive semidefinite matrix are non-negative. Hence, this matrix is not positive semidefinite and it is not a covariance matrix.

Answer (score 0):

In order to show that the matrix $A=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ -1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ can't be a covariance matrix, we need to show that it's not a PSD matrix, i.e., it's sufficient to show an example vector ($\exists \mathbb{x} \in \mathbb{R^2}$), such that $x^TAx<0$.

Let $x=[1,1]^T$, then we have

$x^TAx=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}. \begin{pmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ -1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}.\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} -1 & -1 \end{pmatrix}.\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}=-2 < 0$.

Hence, $A$ is not a PSD matrix and can't be a covariance matrix.